# SQL select with datasource in master page

Tags: sql, select, sqldatasource

I am wondering if it is possible to have a common `SqlDataSource` setup on a master page, then be able to use individual select statement within web pages that are based on that master page.

Comment: Perfectly possible, but highly unwise for a production app. You would be giving full access to your database to the end user. Actually, the H2 database console works this way; but... it's  intended for development purposes only.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. Using aspx what do I wrap around the select statement, eg, asp:sqldatasource. Which does not work